# Merging rows using foreign keys for connections

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, merge, foreign-keys

I have a table in a SQL Server 2005 database that has a lot of connections to other tables. Every so often the base table gets duplicate entries, we've written a stored procedure that moves the data from all connected tables and then deletes the duplicate entry.

The problem is, as the project keeps growing the amount of connected tables is starting to become unmanageable, and sometimes developers forget to update the stored procedure and then the merge procedure will fail.

Is there a smoother merge function available in TSQL? I'm thinking, since all the tables are connected with `foreign keys` the tables that need to be updated/inserted into could quite possibly be calculated just from reading the table connections.

Table structure looks something like this:

```
Main table
------------------------
mainid (PK) | datacolumns...

Sub table 1:
------------------------
subid1 (PK) | mainid (FK) | datacolumns...

Sub table 2:
------------------------
subid2 (PK) | mainid (FK) | datacolumns...

Sub table 3:
------------------------
subid3 (PK) | datacolumns...

Connection table between "Main table" and "Sub table 3":
------------------------
mainid (FK) | subid3 (FK)
```

Now I have two rows in `Main table` that may or may not have child entries in `Sub table 1` and `Connection table`.

`Sub table 1` should be always be updated with the new `mainid`. `Sub table 2` and `Connection table` have unique key restrictions, so they should only be updated with the new `mainid` if an entry doesn't already exist.

This is a gross oversimplification since we're talking more than 20 tables (and growing) that each have their own restrictions on what makes an entry unique, and should/should not copy over the data if they can't exist in the table according to the unique keys.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly a `ON DELETE CASCADE` for necessary foreign keys will solve your problem. This way deleting an entry from the "main" table will delete entries from other tables connected through FK.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to merge data, not delete it.